# I have not been able to type a lowercase "e" for a few days now on VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I type "e" in lowercase. It says not found. It only allows me to type an uppercase "E" and lowercase in the form of other languages other than English. At the bottom of VS code, when I type "e", it says "The key combination (E, E) is not a command." If I continue to press "e",  Can someone please help me with this problem? It's depressing.

I tried everything and was expecting to be able to type an "e"

Comment: It sounds like you may have created a shortcut that uses that character.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code go to `File` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts`

Click `Record Keys` icon in the search field:
[image]

Type lowercase "e"

A list of culprits will be shown. Remove or reset such shortcut(s)